# Bower Packages Dependency Error

Tags: angularjs, bower

We are using `bower` in our admin panel and recently our app stopped working with the error :

[image]

When I expand the error, It is from `angular-sanitize` : 

`f.module("ngSanitize", []).provider("$sanitize", function() {
...
...
...
...
}).info({
        angularVersion: "1.6.3"
    });`

My `bower.json` is

`"dependencies": {
    "angular-resource": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-messages": "~1.5.3",
    "angular": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-local-storage": "~0.2.7",
    "crypto-js": "~3.1.6",
    "ng-file-upload": "~12.0.4",
    "angular-moment": "~0.10.3",
    "angular-ui-calendar": "latest",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.3.1",
    "lodash": "~4.13.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.6",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.5.8",
    "angular-touch": "~1.5.8",
    "angular-spinner": "~0.8.1",
    "angular-jwt": "^0.1.3",
    "ng-intl-tel-input": "~1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.6",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.6.1",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3",
    "mdPickers": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.5.3",
    "angular-material": "^1.1.3",
    "moment": "~2.11.1"
  }`

I made the app run by upgrading

[image]

Now, I can't navigate through any of my routes as the url looks like : 
`localhost:5000/#!/search`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the issue with `angular-material : 1.1.3` .

This latest version of `Angular Material` was forcing bower to install the latest available version of

`angular-aria
angular-sanitize`

That's why

`f.module("ngSanitize", []).provider("$sanitize", function() {
...
...
...
...
}).info({
        angularVersion: "1.6.3"
    });`

was not found in the `1.5.x` version of angular and causing this whole issue.

Restoring `angular-material: 1.1.3 ---> 1.0.0` fixed my issue.